# Unable to serve angular application with ng serve --open

Tags: javascript, angular

[here is the error showing in my powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGnqj.png)

this is the error when I run this command `ng serve --open`

Angular CLI: 9.0.6
Node: 12.16.1
OS: win32 x64

This is my angular cli version:

[image]

Comment: can you please specify the error thrown in your browser too if any?

Comment: when i run this http://localhost:4200/ in browser . the browser only showing unable to connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this error comes. I think you should try to run Angular application by : `ng serve` instead of `ng serve --open` .

I think the issue is because of an environment variable of your system path is missing . Add "`C:\Windows\System32\`" value to your system PATH variable.

Comment: thanks its working but why this command are given in the angular documentation site which actually are not working

Comment: Glad it works. Did you check my second point. I think because of your system configuration it is not working. Otherwise `ng serve --open` command is correct.